# Using s3 to extend summary function

Tags: r

Using below code I'm attempting to re-write the summary function so that just the coefficient is returned :

```
summary <- function(x)
   {
      UseMethod("GetFirst",x)
   }

summary <- function(x)
  {
      return(x$Coefficient)
}

class(summary) <- "mysum"

tosum = as_tibble(c(1,2,3))
tosum

summary(tosum)
```

This returns an error :

```
> summary(tosum)
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'Coefficient'.
```

How to read the available properties on the summary function and invoke using s3 ?

Comment: You've defined `summary()` twice here. And you've over written the default generic method which might break a lot of things. What on earth are you trying to do? Where are these coefficients supposed to come from? What objects are you trying to change the behavior of? I see many different S3 summary methods for many different objects with `methods(summary)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`summary` is already a Generic function so you don't need `UseMethod`. In order to extend its functionality you need to add another method which will work with the class you want.

See an example:

```
summary.myclass <- function(x)
{
  return(x$Coefficient)
}


tosum = data.frame(Coefficient = c(1,2,3))
class(tosum) <- c('myclass', 'data.frame')
summary(tosum)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Here I am defining an extension of `summary` (called method) for the `myclass` class. When I use summary on `tosum` which is of that class then `summary.myclass` is dispatched and the column `Coefficiet` is returned.